# accessing C++ static class member variables in multiple source files

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static-members

I've got a pair of classes. One of them has a set of static const uint32_t's (the following code is a trimmed down example):

```
class Foo {
public:
    static const uint32_t BAZ;
    void RunMe(void);
};
class Bar {
public:
    void RunMeAlso(void);
};
```

I'm doing the usual thing of one class per cpp file, since the actual classes are pretty sizeable, but I've struck a problem. Both `Foo::RunMe()` and `Bar::RunMeAlso()` access the value `Foo::BAZ`.

I've got the definition of `const uint32_t Foo::BAZ = 1;` in foo.cpp, but hit a compile error with it in bar.cpp (where it is used as a case label in a switch statement) in VS2010 (tho this code needs to be portable, but I haven't yet checked it with gcc). Both header files are included in both source files... and trying to put some kind of extern reference in bar.cpp to tell the compiler that it's in a different translation unit doesn't solve it (creates more compile errors)... and of course all the examples I've found on this kind of subject are for the trivial case of single classes/files where someone didn't know/forgot to use the definition in addition to the declaration.

Thoughts, anyone, on how to resolve this? (I would prefer not having to use an enum but will if that's the only other option since I'm sure that will compile!)

TIA,

-J

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: I guess, you should be facing linker error rather than compiler error. Can you post the error ?

Comment: What does the code in bar.cpp look like that references Foo::BAZ?

Comment: Here's the error, just for reference: `bar.cpp(412): error C2051: case expression not constant`. And it is definitely a compiler error, not a linker error. And the code is (given I said it was a label for a case statement): `switch(somevar) { case Foo::BAZ:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case labels must be compiler constants. A static member variable is not a compiler constant, unless it is constant and initialized in the declaration with a constant expression.

So:

- Declare it `static const uint32_t BAZ = 1;` in the header; or
- Use `if` instead of `switch`.

BTW, it is usually helpful to read the actual error message. And post it, if you are going to ask about it...

Comment: I'll remember about posting the error message next time, but you're right: it is about the non-constant case label. I'll go convert to if-else stuff instead, since most of the times I'm actually accessing these constants, the switch statements only have 2 or 3 case statements. Thanks, rodrigo!

Comment: Actually, rodrigo, for completeness' sake, a question about what you said about declaring it. I'm assuming you mean I should put the `=1` into the spot in the class where it is declared, not shift the definition into the header (since this will result in linker errors, right?)

Comment: Yes, of course. A static const member variable, of a simple type, initialized with a constant expression _in the declaration_ is considered a compiler constant, much like an enumeration constant or a global constant. If any of these conditions are not met, then it _is_ a variable, with external linkage and all, and you should not put the definition in the header.